# What is the difference between a SubQuestionQueryEngine and a MultiStepQueryEngine?

Tags: python, llama-index

The title says it: What is the difference between a SubQuestionQueryEngine and a MultiStepQueryEngine?

Intuitively, these things seem very similar: Breaking a question down into multiple steps is very similar to breaking a question down into multiple subquestions. Conceptually, what is the difference between both? In what situation would you use one over the other? Would/could you combine them somehow or does that not make sense?